# Can I make the visible universe charged by firing short lived charged quantum black holes?

Tags: black-holes, conservation-laws, charge, observable-universe

Imagine I fires a couple of negatively charged quantum black hole and each black hole would last probably a second or two before releasing enormous amount of pure energy, haven't I single handedly charged up the entire known universe? Is there any safety mechanism in nature to return the universe back to its original electrically neutral state beside preventing charged black hole from existing in the first place?

Comment: Conservation laws following from gauged symmetries are not violated by gravity. If the universe started out electrically neutral it will remain so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns science fiction as opposed to science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we know the Hawking radiation from a black hole does not violate conservation of charge.

So if you charged your two black holes up to $-Q$ the total charge is initially $-2Q$, and after the evaporation has completed the total charge of all the debris produced is still $-2Q$. You haven't changed the total charge of the universe.